# ultrapower of GLn(F) is ishomprhic to GLn(ultrapower F)

Tags: group-theory, logic, model-theory

I want to proof that :

$\prod_D$GL$_n$($\Bbb F$)$\cong$GL$_n$($\prod_D$$\Bbb F$)

for any ultrafilter D and any field $\Bbb F$.

I was trying to crate an isomorphism between the two stractues as follows :
Let $\varphi$ : $\prod_D$GL$_n$($\Bbb F$)$\to$GL$_n$($\prod_D$$\Bbb F$)

where For any A $\in$ $\prod_D$GL$_n$($\Bbb F$): $\varphi$(A):= [$\varphi$(A$_i$)].

where [$\varphi$(A$_i$)] represents the equivalence class of the matrix $\varphi$(A$_i$) under the ultrapower construction.
Here, $\varphi$(A$_i$) denotes the matrix obtained by applying the mapping $\varphi$ entry-wise to each matrix A$_i$.

To show that $\varphi$ is well-defined, we need to verify that the choice of representative {A$_i$} does not affect the equivalence class $\varphi$(A$_i$).
Suppose we have another representative {B$_i$} for A, where B$_i$ $\in$ GL$_n$($\Bbb F$). Then, for every σ $\in$ D, we have B$_i$σ ≈ A$_i$σ (equivalent matrices). Since $\varphi$ is an entry-wise mapping, it follows that $\varphi$(B$_i$σ) = $\varphi$(A$_i$σ) for every σ $\in$ D. Therefore, [$\varphi$(A$_i$σ)] = [$\varphi$(B$_i$σ)], and $\varphi$(A) is well-defined.

Now I am going to show that $\varphi$ is a group homorphism.
Let A,B $\in$ $\prod_D$GL$_n$($\Bbb F$).
We have:
$\varphi$(A·B) = [$\varphi$(A$_i$·B$_i$)]
= [$\varphi$(A$_i$)·$\varphi$(B$_i$)]
= [$\varphi$(A$_i$)]·[$\varphi$(B$_i$)]
= $\varphi$(A)·$\varphi$(B),
where the first equality follows from the definition of matrix multiplication, and the rest follows from the properties of ultrapowers and matrix multiplication.

To show that $\varphi$ is bijecntion I thought about definding an inverse map
$\psi$ :GL$_n$($\prod_D$$\Bbb F$)$\to$$\prod_D$GL$_n$($\Bbb F$) as follows :
$\psi$(B) = [$\psi$(B$_i$)],
where [$\psi$(B$_i$)] represents the equivalence class of the matrix $\psi$(B$_i$) under the ultrafilter D. Here, $\psi$(B$_i$) denotes the matrix obtained by applying the inverse mapping $\psi$ entry-wise to each matrix B$_i$. Then I would show that $\psi$ is a group hompmorphism and  $\varphi$ inverse hence $\varphi$ is an isomorphsim between the two structes hence: $\prod_D$GL$_n$($\Bbb F$)$\cong$GL$_n$($\prod_D$$\Bbb F$)

Is my proof valid?
Thanks!

Comment: Your definition of $\varphi$: "$\varphi:\prod_D{\rm GL}_n(\Bbb F)\to {\rm GL}_n(\prod_D\Bbb F)$ where [...] $\varphi(A):= [\varphi(A_i)]$ [...] represents the equivalence class of the matrix $\varphi(A_i)$ under the ultrapower construction. Here, $\varphi(A_i)$ denotes the matrix obtained by applying the mapping $\varphi$ entry-wise to each matrix $A_i$" is unclear and seems circular. Same for $\psi.$